# I am getting a error while trying to make a hacked client for minecraft 1.12.2

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft-forge

I am getting this error while trying to make a hacked client for 1.12.2 mc using eclipse, I don't know how to set a mod up so I was using the video from srgantmoomoo. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B0azKVU9t20&t=1474s) I have finally finished doing it and ran it, several times. I have gone as far as starting all over. I have installed jre-8u291 and jdk-8u291 and ran those ones too. I think they are installed. here is my code for main, reference, client proxy, and mcmod.info. If you need any other parts of code I need to send just let me know(error at the bottom)

main

```
import me.cowpiebingo.cowclient.proxy.CommonProxy;
import me.cowpiebingo.cowclient.util.Refrence;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.Instance;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.SidedProxy;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;

@Mod(modid = Refrence.MOD_ID, name = Refrence.NAME, version = Refrence.VERSION)
public class Main {
    
    @Instance
    public Main instance;
    
    @SidedProxy(clientSide = Refrence.CLIENT_PROXY_CLASS, serverSide = Refrence.COMMON_PROXY_CLASS)
    public static CommonProxy proxy;
    
    @EventHandler
    public void PreInit (FMLPreInitializationEvent event) {
        
    }
    
    @EventHandler
    public void init (FMLPreInitializationEvent event) {
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(instance);
        
    }
    
    @EventHandler
    public void PostInit (FMLPreInitializationEvent event) {
        
    }
}
```

reference

```
public class Refrence {
    
    public static final String MOD_ID = "coc";
    public static final String NAME = "CowClient";
    public static final String VERSION = "0.0.1";
    public static final String ACCEPTED_VERSION = "[1.12.2]";
    public static final String CLIENT_PROXY_CLASS = "me.cowpiebingo.cowclient.proxy.ClientProxy";
    public static final String COMMON_PROXY_CLASS = "me.cowpiebingo.cowclient.proxy.CommonProxy";

}
```

ClientProxy

```
public class ClientProxy extends CommonProxy {

}
```

and mcmod.info

```
{
  "modid": "coc",
  "name": "CowClient",
  "description": "for 2b2t",
  "version": "${0.0.1}",
  "mcversion": "${1.12.2}",
  "url": "",
  "updateUrl": "",
  "authorList": ["CowPieBingo"],
  "credits": "The Forge and FML guys, for making this example",
  "logoFile": "",
  "screenshots": [],
  "dependencies": []
}
```

the error

```
[2021-05-30 13:10:49] [INFO   ] Main Class: net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch 
[2021-05-30 13:10:49] [INFO   ] Srg2Mcp: C:\Users\Eli S\Desktop\CowClient\build\createSrgToMcp\output.srg 
[2021-05-30 13:10:49] [INFO   ] Extra: [] 
[2021-05-30 13:10:49] [INFO   ] Running with arguments: [--version, $1.12.2, --assetIndex, 1.12, --assetsDir, C:\Users\Eli S\.gradle\caches\forge_gradle\assets, --accessToken, {REDACTED}, --userProperties, [], --tweakClass, net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker] 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.Main.start(Main.java:86)
    at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.MainClient.main(MainClient.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.<init>(Launch.java:34)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Class cast Exception - Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52385610/java-class-cast-exception-spring-boot)

Comment: tl;dr of dupe: You're not using Java 8. You probably have both it and a newer Java version installed, and the newer one is taking precedence.

Comment: How would I go on to changing it to an older version?

Comment: If you are running this in Eclipse the Java that is used is specified on the "Run Configuration" for the program - "Run > Run Configurations". You may need to tell Eclipse about the Java 8 install in "Java > Installed JREs" in the Preferences.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to tell eclipse about the JRE because whenever I click add, then standard VM, I don't know where to go from there. If there is a YT video that might be able to help could you maybe let me know, please?

Comment: NVM I finally got it working