# Hive does not launch in Ubuntu 20.04 and throws error

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am setting up hive after I setup hadoop on my personal machine. However after I install all the steps to configure hive I am still unable to use hive. I see the following error message:

```
    hadoop@ub:/usr/local/hive/lib$ hive
    SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop-3.3.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
    SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
    Hive Session ID = d7574f3f-4ec1-4fac-bbbd-631c5f698e3c
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.java:413)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.java:389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliSessionState.<init>(CliSessionState.java:60)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:683)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
```

When I run jps I get the following:

```
hadoop@acharya-ub:/usr/local/hive/lib$ jps
4866 Jps
28644 SecondaryNameNode
28117 NameNode
28965 ResourceManager
29353 NodeManager
28349 DataNode
```

After searching over the internet, I found that running hiverser2 helped them but it hasn't helped me and I still get the same error message even after I start hiveserver2 service.

I am using java 11, hadoop-3.3.0 and apache-hive-3.1.2

I created symbolic links for the hadoop and hive locations:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Sep 1 22:39 hadoop -> /usr/local/hadoop-3.3.0 
drwxr-xr-x 11 hadoop hadoop 4096 Sep 1 22:46 hadoop-3.3.0 
drwxrwxr-x 10 hadoop hadoop 4096 Sep 1 23:02 apache-hive-3.1.2-bin 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Sep 1 23:03 hive -> /usr/local/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/
```

I then setup the following in my .bashrc file:

```
HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
HIVE_HOME=usr/local/hive
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to run? If a sql terminal, you want `beeline`, not `hive`

Comment: Maybe you are missing a JAVA_HOME. Not related to hive but check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52385610/java-class-cast-exception-spring-boot). Also try to use `beeline` intead of `hive` shell