# jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader incompatible with java.net.URLClassLoader (j8 - j11)

Tags: java, java-11, agent, instrumentation

I created a custom class to add urls into a class loader dynamically.

```
   void addURL(URL url) {
         try {
             Class<?>[] parameters = new Class[]{URL.class};
             Class<?> sysclass = URLClassLoader.class;
             Method method = sysclass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", parameters);
             method.setAccessible(true);

             URLClassLoader sysloader = (URLClassLoader) (getClass().getClassLoader());
             while (sysloader != null) {
                 method.invoke(sysloader, url);
                 sysloader = (URLClassLoader) sysloader.getParent();
             }
         }catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
          }
```

And then I'm trying to add the url with the following method

String filePath = "jar path";

```
File file = new File(filePath);
URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
    CustomClassLoader customURLClassLoader = new CustomClassLoader();
    customURLClassLoader.addURL(url);
```

I'm getting the following exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Class cast Exception - Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52385610/java-class-cast-exception-spring-boot)

Comment: thank you for the suggestions; didn't resolved it

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should provide complete the [complete error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough) and a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You're doing something which is not valid anymore in Java 9 and higher. The type of the system classloader changed, so you can't just cast to URLClassLoader and expect it to work.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel to be more precise, this has never been valid at all. It just happened to work in a specific implementation.

Comment: Since this question has been tagged with “agent” and “instrumentation”, an explanation is needed why you don’t use the Instrumentation API but resort to this hack.

Comment: If you use an agent, then just call [Instrumentation.appendToSystemClassLoaderSearch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#appendToSystemClassLoaderSearch%28java.util.jar.JarFile%29).

Answer (score 1):

You you have tagged this question with both [agent](/questions/tagged/agent) and [instrumentation](/questions/tagged/instrumentation) - so you may actually be interested in adding a jar to the system class loader from a *javaagent*.

The `Instrumentation` interface already has a supported method to do exactly that: [`Instumentation.appendToSystemClassLoaderSearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#appendToSystemClassLoaderSearch%28java.util.jar.JarFile%29).

By using this supported method you avoid all the problems that the reflective solution has - as this method is part of Java, it will be updated to account for any internal changes - preserving its functionality.